# Best way to manage login credential in JavaScript and Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have problem to store login details to more secure at client site.
Details like Authentication Token, UserId, user email, name and encrypted password.

Comment: I don't think you should be storing the hashed password on the client side. Not really much need for it if you have a token already.

Comment: Please, never store that kind of data on the client side. Store everything in a database, and keep sensitive information encrypted.

Comment: Why don't you just create a session token? You can store everything on the database matching session table with users

Answer (score 1):

[Do not store the password locally](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q). If any of the browsers has a flaw, your security has a flaw. Also, if you manage to steal someone's browser data (e.g. session hack), they now also have the encrypted password, which brings us to: ***[Never](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/why-should-i-hash-passwords)*** store [a password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124905/why-dont-we-store-passwords-in-a-database-using-encryption-instead-of-hashing) other than [hashed](https://www.securityinnovationeurope.com/blog/page/whats-the-difference-between-hashing-and-encrypting). There are so many risks and no benefits because:

You have a Auth token, which is your identification to the server. Often there are also [refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current). This is a 2nd token. If the auth token expires, you send the auth+refresh token en get a new Atuh token. This way, passwords to not need to be stored.

Comment: I need best way to store and retrieve data without request to server like in mobile application to store Auth data in local.

Comment: haha, just re-read my answer again. You really only need the Auth token and a refresh token. *Never store passwords*, and if you must, never ever clientside. The first link in my answer is to a youtube channel, I suggest you watch it.

Comment: Token i can store but for id i again need to request server i don't want to do this.

Comment: No, again, you do not need the password. You need a refreshtoken. I suggest you research this a bit more, I think you're misunderstanding the concept of the tokens :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to store details other than token. You can always get data back by querying the server with authentication token.